# Is there a way to set a custom cell text size in pine script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I want to create a script that shows a custom watermark in TradingView. I have this current script which works but I want the text to be larger. Is there a way to add a custom text size or just make the text larger?

```
//@version=5
indicator("Watermark", overlay = true)

wm_col = input.color(color.new(color.gray, 75), title = "", inline = "WM")
watermark_txt  = input.string("Custom Text", title = "Enter Text")

var watermark = table.new("middle_center", 1, 1)

if barstate.isfirst
    table.cell_set_text(watermark, 0, 0, text = watermark_txt)
    table.cell_set_text_color(watermark, 0, 0, text_color = wm_col)
    table.cell_set_text_size(watermark, 0, 0, text_size = size.huge)
```

Answer (score 1):

While Tradingview allows many sizes, including size.auto, size.tiny, size.small, size.normal, size.large, and size.huge, you are already using size.huge, which is the largest.

I'm not sure what your goals are, but you could consider alternative methods of watermarking, like placing the text in several places across the screen, or adding labels across the screen to catch the eye more. Here's an example:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Watermark", overlay = true)

var label myLabel = na
wm_col = input.color(color.new(color.gray, 75), title = "", inline = "WM")
watermark_txt  = input.string("Custom Text", title = "Enter Text")

var watermark = table.new(position.middle_center, 1, 1)

if barstate.isfirst
    table.cell_set_text(watermark, 0, 0, text = watermark_txt)
    table.cell_set_text_color(watermark, 0, 0, text_color = wm_col)
    table.cell_set_text_size(watermark, 0, 0, text_size = size.huge)
    
if barstate.islast
    myLabel := label.new(x=bar_index, y=close, text="More Text Here", style=label.style_label_down, size=size.large, textcolor=color.white)
```

Which would stand out more:

[image]